# OpenGL program works only in Debug mode in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2013, release

my small OpenGL application works fine in Debug mode, but if I build it in Release mode I often get this error:

```
Shader Creation Error:
- Vertex shader failed to compile with the following errors:
ERROR: 0:22: error(#132) Syntax error: "]" parse error
ERROR: error(#273) 1 compilation errors.  No code generateder code here
```

The strange thing is, that the error occurs most of the time, but sometimes the program works fine. I think it has something to do with the filestream, but I cannot figure out what it is.

This is the corresponding part of my code:

```
    std::ifstream file(fp);
    if(!file) crit_error("Shader Loading", ("file "+fp+" doesn't exist").c_str());

    file.seekg(0, file.end);
    GLint len = GLint(file.tellg());
    file.seekg(0, file.beg);

    GLchar* buf = new GLchar[len];
    file.read(buf, len);
    file.close();

    std::string type = fp.substr(fp.size()-4, 4);
    if(type == ".vsh")
        id = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    else if(type == ".fsh")
        id = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    else if(type == ".csh")
        id = glCreateShader(GL_COMPUTE_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(id, 1, (const GLchar**)&buf, &len);
    glCompileShader(id);

    delete[] buf;
```

Comment: Try writing `buf` to a file and looking at it.  Perhaps you're off by one or something like that.  Not really enough of your code shown here to know that.  It would help your question to show how you find `len`, and what `fp` is.

Comment: yes I forgot that part sorry

Comment: Can someone tell me why I got -1 for the question? what I have done wrong?

Comment: You might consider reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help you ask better questions.  Not including a good example is a common reason for downvotes and a simple one to avoid.  Many times just the act of distilling your code into a simple example will help you solve the problem before you even need to ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
file.seekg(0, file.end);
GLint len = GLint(file.tellg());
file.seekg(0, file.beg);

GLchar* buf = new GLchar[len];
file.read(buf, len);
file.close();
```

This code reads **exactly** the length of the file and nothing more. And unfortunately file sizes don't actually tell you about how much there's actually to read; if the file read exits short it will leave in any garbage that was in the memory `buf` points to before it was allocated to your program. *This explains why it works in debug mode: In debug mode buffers are usually allocated a little bit larger to allow for out-of-bounds access detection and variables and buffers left uninitialized by the programmer are set to zero. While useful for some debugging this may turn regular bugs into [Heisenbugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug).*

Furthermore `ifstream::read` may return less than the requested amount of bytes, for example if you run into an end of file situation and leave the rest of the buffer untouched. As it happens `ifstream::get` will return NUL if you're hitting the end of file, so it will fill up your buffer with terminating NUL bytes.

The proper way to read a file being passed into C string processing functions is this:

```
file.seekg(0, file.end);
GLint len = GLint(file.tellg());
file.seekg(0, file.beg);

GLchar* buf = new GLchar[len + 1];
buf[len] = 0;
file.read(buf, len);
streamsize rb = file.gcount();
if( rb < len ) {
    /* file read short */
    /* either way zero out the remainder of
     * the buffer untouched by the read. */
    memset(buf + rb, 0, len - rb);

    /* should also log some warning message here. */
}
file.close();
```

Comment: Same here. Thanks a lot. How do you know all this? This is not taught in any article I have ever encountered.

Comment: @Ankitsinghkushwah: Experience mostly. And reading lots of code and more importantly *specifications!* At the end of the day, tutorials will always omit information to be concise.

Answer (score -1):

OK. I simply tried a different reading method and it worked.

```
    GLchar* buf = new GLchar[len];

    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        buf[i] = file.get();    

    file.close();
```

I think this is a bug of the Visual C++ compiler.

Comment: That's rather unlikely.  There's probably still a problem in the code and you've managed to accidentally mask it, for now.  You might consider actually checking the error codes from functions that can fail, like `read`.

Comment: It may be unlikely, but isn't it strange, that it worked perfectly in debug mode and in release mode just sometimes? And I just changed the file.read() to file.get() and suddenly it worked in release mode, too.

Comment: There are thousands of programs reading terabytes of files every day developed with Visual Studio.  It's not a compiler bug, it's something in your program that you didn't share.

Comment: You are certainly right. Even so, I assure you that I didn't change any other code and that this part is the only relevant. Why do you think this is impossible. Think about all the complex interactions between the application and the OS on my hardware. It could be a problem that only affects my computer, only in the case of using the read data for OpenGL shader loading. It is unlikely but possible, or am I wrong?

Comment: I'm sure that must be it.  Hopefully you won't find any other compiler bugs.

Comment: It's not a bug of the compiler, you're neglecting to add a terminating NUL byte to your read string, that gets passed to glShaderSource. That it works is in Debug mode is no surprise, because in Debug mode uninitialized variables are usually set to 0 and memory allocation zeroes out the allocated memory block, with the allocation usually being larger than the requested size. Hence you get that missing NUL byte you omitted after reading.

Comment: Ah I understand. Thanks for the answer. I did not mean it totally serious. It was late just very late ... and fun to argue about :)